# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass with DataTables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, server-side

I have just implemented datatables based off Ryan Bates' rails cast #340 'http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?autoplay=true' and I am receiving this error 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass'. Everywhere I have looked people are saying it is because what you are trying to call is undefined but in this case I am unsure why this is an error as this is being defined and I have followed this rails cast to the last detail.

The error i'm getting is "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" The stack trace is as follows:

```
Showing /Users/calligouser/Documents/CalligoProjects/cloudcentrev2/app/views/ips/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:

<li class="left"><%= select_tag 'ip_status_id', options_for_select(@ip_statuses, @status_id), { prompt: "All" } %></li>
```

This error .map is being made in the controller when defining @ip_statuses. The code goes to the model where it retrieves a hash of values as follows:

```
STATUSES = { 0 => "Unallocated",
           1 => "Allocated",
           2 => "Reserved",
           3 => "Transient"
}
```

I am trying to load a datatable of IP addresses in an IP index view.

IP Controller (index)

```
def index

    @ips = Ip.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: IpsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end

    @ip_statuses = Ip::STATUSES.map {|key,value| [value,key]}
end
```

ips_datatable.rb file for datatables options

```
class IpsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialise(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i
      iTotalRecords: Ip.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: ips.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end


private

  def data
    ips.map do |ip|
      [
        link_to(ip.ip_address, ip),
        h(ip.system_name),
        h(ip.description),
        h(ip.system_location),
        h(ip.status)
      ]
    end
  end

  def ips
    @ips ||= fetch_ips
  end

  def fetch_ips
    ips = Ip.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    ips = ips.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      ips = ips.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}")
    end
    ips
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[ip_address system_name system_location description status]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end

end
```

IPs JQuery file

```
 jQuery ->

  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # DataTables Server Side
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $('#ip-table').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#ip-table').data('source')
```

IP Table form view

```
<table id="ip-table" class="full display" data-source="<%= products_url(format: "json") %>">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ip address</th>
            <th>System name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>System location</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Edit / Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>

      </table>
```

**EDIT:** I have found that the application doesn't reach beyond the respond_to block, so I attempted to debug within the ip_datatables file and the application seems to be failing before reaching the code in the file. I used a puts '....' after format.json line of code and it does reach this, but for some reason it doesn't return from within the ip_datatables file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I actually found the problem to this. In the controller I removed everything other than the respond to block and placed this code above it:

```
@ip_statuses = Ip::STATUSES.map {|key,value| [value,key]}

if !session[:ip_status_id].nil? then @status_id = session[:ip_status_id] else @status_id = 1 end
@ips = @ips.where(status: @status_id) unless @status_id == ""
```

I then removed the :h from the delegation in the ips_datatable file and removed all instances of the 'h' method being used. I then filled in missing commas in the ips_datatable file.

I also had to remove the edit / delete header from the html table as the datatable won't recognise this as it isn't actually a column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write the stacktrace, so I don't know where the error is.

Anyway... fix the typpo in your `ips_datatable.rb`

the method name is `def initialize` and not `initialise`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm used to the English spelling. I have updated the question to include that error location

Answer (score 0):

The data function references ips, at which point ips appears to be null. My guess would be that it's the line in your fetch_ips function

```
ips = ips.page(page).per_page(per_page)
```

Though I can't speak as to what you want it to be, I can say that you need to rename your page and per_page functions to make it clearer what that line is doing.

You should start commenting out things that are excess steps in order to get it working, starting with the line that I mentioned.  In fact, you should probably start by reducing your fetch_ips function simply to

```
ips = Ip.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```

and testing to see if that much at least works.  Then once you have it working you can start adding things back in.

You might also want to have the people over at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) take a look at it once you get it working as you intend to.

**EDIT:** If that doesn't work you might try adjusting the line `ips.map do |ip|` to something along the lines of `ips.tap{|a| puts a}.map do |ip|` in order to see what ips actually is at this point.  Confirm that it is null at this point, showing that this is indeed the place that the error is pointing at, and then work through the code to figure out why...  If it isn't actually null at that point, then there is somewhere else the error is pointing to, that is not included with the code that you posted.  The goal here is to identify where the exception is thrown then work backwards to determine why it was thrown.

My guess was/is that it is related to the fetch_ips function which you might try eliminating by changing the data function `ips.map` to be `Ip.all.map`.  But again that is working with the assumption that ips.map is the line where that exception is being raised, so confirm that.

Comment: I commented the rest of the code in the fetch_ips method as you suggested, however the error is still present. In regards to the page and per_page methods, I believe they are called page and per_page because they control the pagination of the table so there is no reason to give them a specific name based on the table itself.

Comment: @JackO'Connor I edited my answer to offer some more ideas to help you debug it.  Also, I'm not saying you should rename page and per_page to be table specific, I simply think you should name them something other than page and per_page.  Having two functions with the same name in the same scope is asking for trouble.